# UNIX C - Simple write() operation keeps failing

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I want to create a file named "common.txt" if said file does not exist, then append to it a single char.

This is my relevant code:

```
char buffer3[2];
buffer3[0]='Z';
buffer3[1]='\0';

//open
filed=open("common.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND, O_WRONLY);

//append
int result=write(filed, buffer3, 2);

if(result==-1){
    cout << "WRITE FAILED!" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "WRITE SUCCEEDED!" << endl;
}

//close
close(filed);
```

write() keep returning -1. I tried values of 1, 2, and 3 for the 3rd argument of write() but that didn't work either. Maybe my open() flags are incorrect.

Comment: Is `open` sucessful?

Comment: btw you may define your buffer more simply: `char *buffer3 = "Z";`. Then you don't have to manually null terminate it. Also, in `write` the third parameter could be `strlen(buffer3)`.

Comment: Open was successful with a return value of 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `open()` incorrectly.  It should be more like this:

```
open("common.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0666);
```

You were missing the `mode` argument which is mandatory when creating a file (omitting it is undefined behavior!).  Or rather, you were passing `O_WRONLY` as the mode, which is incorrect, and you were failing to pass any of the mandatory read/write flags in the `flags`.

And of course you need to add a check that `open()` actually succeeds.

Comment: Works perfect now haha. Thanks <3